# Sharepoint Master Page & Layout Design

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage, design

is there a way to make the Sharepoint looks like the picture below (without html coding)? As what I know, most of the Sharepoint with amazing design is powered by paid software such as Shortpoint. I was trying to use free template found on Google but ended up I realized that the template is actually for publishing site not enterprise wiki site.

[image]

Comment: i think you can do it without paid software using HTML jquery and CSS. Modern wiki pages are having inbuilt News Webpart and Site Owners, Tiles View just you have to arrange and Apply proper CSS to match your site. https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-build-a-cool-intranet-landing-page-using-modern-page-experience-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1):

For what environment are you looking for? SharePoint 2013/2016 onPrem or online? Online will be at least a little bit more tricky as there's the access to masterpage/pagelayout restricted. Modern UI is far harder to customize with just HTML and CSS.
If we're talking about onPrem environments, you're lucky (with a lot of things to learn). In the case above the left handed navigation is disabled/not shown. The pagelayout is two-rowed with three columns in the second row. Each column got one Web Part Zone. The best way to learn is to copy a pagelayout you want and do some changes in it.

SharePoint gives you a nice and handy support with the html templates you can use following this technet: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-a-page-layout-in-sharepoint